# Linking openURL cannot read value from json data

Tags: react-native

Hello i got a problem using react native component Linking for show something at the browser, the problem is when i get value from axios response data.

my code :

```
    'use strict';
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    BackHandler,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Text,
    AsyncStorage,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    Modal,
    Linking,
    WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class Pay extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }

    getUrlPay(){
        axios{
            ...
            if(response.data == "success"){
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data.data
                })
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openUrl(this.state.data.url)}>
                <Text>OpenPay</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

Error is undefined is not an object

my response value is "https://something.com".

Any solution?

Comment: Post  related code

Comment: What you get in if(response.data == "success"){ console.log()

Comment: url: "https://something.com"

Comment: Try to use arrow functions like getUrlPay=()=>{  and then() in axios

Comment: Else you need post all your code of component without ...